# Running Python on Windows from Shell

Tags: python, windows, shell

So I've got some script named 'some_class.py' located in the same folder as python.exe:

```
from __future__ import print_function

class some_class:
    def say_it(self):
    print('hello')

def main():
    instance = some_class()
    instance.say_it()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I try running it with the following command while in Python Shell inside PowerShell:

```
some_class.py
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'some_class' is not defined
```

Python's version is 3.4.1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try "python some_class.py".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run it  using the filename then don't start a python shell just `python34 some_class.py` from a cmd prompt. The `if __name__ == '__main__':` will mean the `main()`  function will be run when the script is executed. If you import the script it will not be run, that is the point of using `if __name__ == '__main__'`

Answer (score 2):

You generally don't put your python programs into the folder you've installed python to -- that's not how it's supposed to be.

Also, python will not look into the directory of python.exe when looking for python modules, it looks into $PYTHONPATH (by default, into its library folders) and into the current working directory (which is the directory you were in *when* you called python.exe, not *where* python.exe itself lies.

You'll also have to import your file if you want to use things from it, so when in an interactive shell, you'd probably do

```
import my_python_file
```

I think you should go back to python.org and read the tutorial from start to end. It has a nice section on working with files, what modules actually are and how to use functionality from other files.

Comment: I've tried calling python.exe from the folder where some_class.py is located. I've then imported my file, but I get the same error when trying to actually use the class. I also didn't find any tutorial which get down to the module theory on python.org. Launching the file from outside the shell as @padraic-cunningham suggested actually worked.

Comment: Python's import system uses `sys.path`, not `PYTHONPATH`. That optional environment variable is just one way among many to extend `sys.path`.